# Prisma ORM : orderBy on table of relation

Tags: node.js, orm, prisma

We are trying into a prisma.order.findFirst to orderBy date asc the activitys of activityOrder which have an order table statut attributes ='PENDING' and a order table attributes tableId=req.params.id,

There is the code below of our prisma.order.findFirst :

```
const ActivityOfPendingOrder = await prisma.order.findFirst({
    where: {
        tableId: req.params.id,
        statut: 'PENDING',
    },
    include: {
        ActivityOrder: {
            select: {
                activity: {
                    orderBy:{
                        date: 'asc'
                    },
                    select: {
                        description: true,
                        date: true,
                        img: true,
                        subImg: true,
                        author: {
                            select: {
                                firstName: true,
                                lastName: true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
        },
    },
})
```

Before adding OrderBy we never had problem with the code of ActivityOfPendingOrder.

We followed the documentation about filtering-and-sorting with prisma : https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/filtering-and-sorting.